# Webpack: Read local node modules for a dependency

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have installed two dependencies, A and B. Both use another dependency, C. But A needs the different version of C and B needs different. NPM handles it by installing 'C' dependency to local node_modules of B.

```
 Main path -> node_modules -> A, C with different version(parallel to A path),
 B -> node_modules -> C with different version(inside node_modules of B dependency).
```

This is well handled by NPM but here comes the problem because of webpack config. In my case both dependencies are picking/reading external dependency i.e. parallel to A and B, that's working for A but needs the dependency inside its local node_modules.

We write the absolute path and webpack converts it to relative paths. I am not sure what causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after investing my whole day, I found the solution for it.

**Reason:**

Basically, the problem is I was passing node_modules path by resolving them to my app directory path

```
const appDirectory = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd());
const resolveApp = relativePath => path.resolve(appDirectory, relativePath);

paths.appModules = resolveApp('node_modules');
paths.appSrc = resolveApp('src');

 module.exports = {
   ....

   modules: [paths.appModules, paths.appSrc].concat(
      // It is guaranteed to exist because we tweak it in `env.js`
      process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean)
   ),
  ...
}
```

so here the normal Node resolution mechanism was not working in case of dependency conflicts and was resolving to external modules in every case.

**Solution:**

Change webpack resolve's `module` to below code

```
 module.exports = {
   ....

   modules: ['node_modules', paths.appSrc].concat(
      // It is guaranteed to exist because we tweak it in `env.js`
      process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean)
   ),
  ...
}
```

Hope this will help someone!!!!